# Quais são os erros neste código usando EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Quais são os erros ou práticas inadequadas neste código?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var db = new AccountingSystemContainer())
    {
        var invHeader = db.InvoiceHeaderSet.Create();
        var invDetail = db.InvoiceDetailSet.Create();

        invHeader.Total = 150m;

        invDetail.ItemDescription = "Algum Item";
        invDetail.Price = 75m;
        invDetail.Quantity = 2;

        invHeader.InvoiceDetail.Add(invDetail);

        db.InvoiceHeaderSet.Add(invHeader);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public partial class InvoiceDetail
{
    public int InvoiceDetail_Id { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceHeaderInvoiceHeader_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual InvoiceHeader InvoiceHeader { get; set; }
}

public partial class InvoiceHeader
{
    public InvoiceHeader()
    {
        this.InvoiceDetail = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
    }

    public int InvoiceHeader_Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetail { get; set; }
}

public partial class AccountingSystemContainer : DbContext
{
    public AccountingSystemContainer()
        : base("name=AccountingSystemContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceHeader> InvoiceHeaderSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetailSet { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Nomenclatura de Chaves

Os nomes usados para chaves primárias [estão fora da convenção padrão de pesquisa de Ids do Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.idkeydiscoveryconvention(v=vs.113).aspx). O correto seria:

```
public partial class InvoiceDetail
{
    public int InvoiceDetailId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class InvoiceHeader
{
    public int InvoiceHeaderId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Ou então:

```
public partial class InvoiceDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class InvoiceHeader
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Ou ainda, se o banco já existe e você quer usar os nomes que estejam fora da convenção, pode usar assim:

```
[Table("INVOICE_DETAIL")]
public partial class InvoiceDetail
{
    [Key]
    [Column("InvoiceDetail_Id")]
    public int InvoiceDetail_Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

[Table("INVOICE_HEADER")]
public partial class InvoiceHeader
{
    [Key]
    [Column("InvoiceHeader_Id")]
    public int InvoiceHeader_Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

## 2. Inicialização de Propriedades de Navegação no Construtor

O Entity Framework inicializa as propriedades de navegação sozinho. Você não precisa inicializar nada, até porque este esforço é inútil. O Entity Framework fará nova atribuição das propriedades de navegação quando assim achar necessário:

```
public partial class InvoiceHeader
{
    // Retire
    /* public InvoiceHeader()
    {
        this.InvoiceDetail = new HashSet<InvoiceDetail>();
    } */
    ...
}
```

## 3. [`UnintentionalCodeFirstException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.unintentionalcodefirstexception(v=vs.113).aspx) em [`OnModelCreating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx)

Aqui não é bem erro: é uma observação. O código abaixo previne você de realizar qualquer mudança estrutural em banco:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
}
```

Como possivelmente você está usando Model/Database First para mapear um banco de dados que já existe, é pertinente manter a anotação apenas para garantir que o Entity Framework não fará qualquer alteração em banco.

Entretanto, é importante dizer que, se o banco de dados não estiver idêntico aos *Models* mapeados em sua aplicação, a chance de erro é bem grande.

## 4. Outros Detalhes

Aqui não são erros. São observações que podem ser pertinentes para seu desenvolvimento.

Não está claro pra mim o porquê da nomenclatura de um contexto de dados como `AccountingSystemContainer`. Não deixa claro ao programador que se trata de um `DbContext`.

Os `DbSet`s não precisam ter `Set` ao final. Se são propriedades que pertencem ao contexto, muito provavelmente serão `DbSet`s (com algumas exceções, como [`Database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.database(v=vs.113).aspx)).